# Configuring WKInterfaceTable row controller at load time

Tags: watchkit

I'm doing most of my watch app UI in code and would like to configure row controller's IB properties at load time, before I access it with `rowController(at:)`.

Is there an easy way to do it? All IB properties are `nil` at `init()`, and `awakeFromNib()` is not available for `NSObject` in WatchKit.

Answer (score 0):

Your IBOutlets must be already bound to your custom table row class which is used in your Interface storyboard. In the custom row class you can update the interface controls by setting the object keeping the information to display.

```
class TableMainCellType: NSObject {

    @IBOutlet weak var label:WKInterfaceLabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var group:WKInterfaceGroup!

    var item:MyTableItem? {

        didSet{

            label.setText(item?.title)
            group.setBackgroundColor(item?.color)
        }
    }    
}
```

To update the table cells I would iterate in the function to update the table view in the InterfaceController like below.

```
// ...
for index in tableItems.indices{

    if let row = self.table.rowController(at: index) as? TableMainCellType {
        let item = tableItems[index]
        row.item = item
    }
}
// ...
```